# How can i make an ID that adds Every time but doesnt Remove Zeros(0)

Tags: java

hey guys i have this id ABCD000000001XYZL

```
public class SmartCounter {
 public String SmartCounter(String strID){
 intNumber =Integer.parseInt(strID.replaceAll("\\D+",""));
 intNumber += 1;
 strReturn = "ABCD"+intNumber+"XYZL";
 (strReturn);           
 }
}
```

Im just asking how can i add 1 to the Number part and return it into a string without loosing the zeros? TIA :D

Comment: Look into String.printf. Or MessageFormat.

Comment: Are `ABCD` and `XYZL` always the same - you have them hardcoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `id` is of the format

- 4 letters
- 9 numbers
- 4 letters

You can parse it using Regex, increment the number, then rebuild it. Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\D{4})(\\d{9})(\\D{4})");
    final String input = "ABCD000000001XYZL";
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        final String head = matcher.group(1);
        final long number = Long.parseLong(matcher.group(2)) + 1;
        final String tail = matcher.group(3);
        final String result = String.format("%s%09d%s", head, number, tail);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

You can use snazzier Regex and the `Matcher.appendReplacement` to make the code a little shorter; at the cost of complexity:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\D{4})(\\d{9})(?=\\D{4})");
    final String input = "ABCD000000001XYZL";
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    final StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    if (matcher.find()) {
        final long number = Long.parseLong(matcher.group(1)) + 1;
        matcher.appendReplacement(result, String.format("%09d", number));
    }
    matcher.appendTail(result);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) I'm sure you can figure out the details on your own

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String.format(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) and something like this,

```
class SmartCounter {
    private int id = 1;

    public SmartCounter() {
        this.id = 1;
    }

    public SmartCounter(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String smartCounter() {
        return String.format("ABCD%09dXYZL", id++);
    }
}
```

Which you can run like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SmartCounter sc = new SmartCounter();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println(sc.smartCounter());
    }
}
```

Output is

```
ABCD000000001XYZL
ABCD000000002XYZL
ABCD000000003XYZL
```